# Pasting into a metadata column

Tags: column, managed-metadata, copy-and-paste

So I am moving our phone inventory over to SharePoint, and I have created numerous columns.  Three of the columns use metadata, and so when I paste the items into the field I get the little red box around all items in those three columns.  All I have to do is double click on the column and it recognizes whats input and its fine.  However Im not going to double click on 1000+ cells to have them check in.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If it's not already, can you get your phone inventory into a spreadsheet and use the Import from Spreadsheet feature in SharePoint?